# hiding rows with If statement for a calander

Tags: excel, vba

So I am a student and my chef gave me the task of making the occupancy plan in excel more dynamic. Now I want to hide the columns if they dont belong to the specific month but it doesnt work like I want it. The days are now only shown up to the 28. of every month.
What is wrong here?

```
Sub montatslen()

Dim spaltenr As Integer

For spaltenr = 32 To 34
    If Cells(3, 7).Value = Month(Cells(14, spaltenr).Value) Then
        Columns(spaltenr).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Columns(spaltenr).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next spaltenr
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried writing it this way and it seemed to work. It hides columns AF, AG and AH

```
Sub montatslen()

Dim spaltenr As Integer

For spaltenr = 32 To 34
    
    columnLetter = Split(Cells(1, spaltenr).Address, "$")(1)
    
    If Range("G3").Value = Month(Range(columnLetter & "14").Value) Then
        Columns(spaltenr).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Columns(spaltenr).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next spaltenr

End Sub
```

Comment: So I noticed my code works too, I just messed up the row and the column number.. :D I should have written `Cells(7, 3) instead`.

Comment: Your code work perfectly fine too.

Comment: Makes sense, that's why I usually try to use Range rather than Cells on my VBA codes, otherwise I can get confused easily.